# Use reflection to find all public virtual methods and provide an override

Tags: .net, reflection, overriding

I have a project where I want to be able to iterate across an instance of a class and find all methods that are marked public virtual.  Then I want to override the instance of the class so that when the method is called I can call a different set of code.  I know how to find all methods that are public in a class using reflection, but I cannot figure out how to override virtual methods.

Basically I am giving a proxy object to use, and when they call the method, I want to call a method on the underlying object.  I can do this by manually overriding each and every method, but I would like to use something a bit more dynamic.

Comment: Interesting question. That would be quite a hack. For what purpose do you want this?

Answer (score 5):

```
typeof(MyClass)
    .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Where(m => m.IsVirtual);
```

Comment: Ok, so now I need a way to substitute that method for a delegate.  Meaning that when someone calls it, I want to execute my delegate instead, passing all the arguments from the method call into my delegate.

Comment: @user: Post a new question to ask that. Also see [`DynamicObject.TryGetMember()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trygetmember.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

MethodBase has an [IsVirtual Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.isvirtual.aspx).

```
MethodBase m = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("MyMethod");
if (m.IsVirtual)
  // yada-yada-yada...
```

Comment: Ok, so now I need a way to substitute that method for a delegate.  Meaning that when someone calls it, I want to execute my delegate instead, passing all the arguments from the method call into my delegate.