# How to find all methods that are declared as virtual in c# using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, virtual

For example

```
public class UserInfo {}

public interface IUser
{
  UserInfo Get(int id);
  string GetData(int id);
}

public class User : IUser
{
    public UserInfo Get(int id)
    {
        return null;
    }
    public virtual string GetData(int id)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I tried the following but it returns true for both methods.

```
MethodInfo[] methods=typeof(User).GetMethods();
foreach(MethodInfo method in methods)
{
   if(method.IsVirtual)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(method.Name);
   }
}
```

Expected Output

```
GetData
```

Actual Output

```
Get
GetData
```

This link is some what similar but not working in my case:
[use-reflection-to-find-all-public-virtual-methods-and-provide-an-override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750730/use-reflection-to-find-all-public-virtual-methods-and-provide-an-override)

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/Gv0taZ). Can you provide a real, minimal, compilable, runnable example?

Comment: Indeed, I had to do multiple things to test this from the original question: 1) Add a UserInfo class. 2) Add an IUser class. 3) Fix the "P" being public. 4) use `typeof(User)` instead of `typeof(Base)`. None of these are things that someone answering the question should have to do. Please provide short but *complete* code examples in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `Get` is a virtual method in that it implements `IUser.Get` and so is *called* using execution-time dispatch - I suspect, anyway. (You haven't given us a complete program, so I've had to guess.)

If you actually want "methods that can be overridden" you also need to check [`MethodBase.IsFinal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.isfinal(v=vs.110).aspx). So just change your loop to:

```
foreach (MethodInfo method in methods)
{
   if (method.IsVirtual && !method.IsFinal)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(method.Name);
   }
}
```

Comment: This is correct, if you (OP) remove the IUser interface from your User class, you will see your expected result. Adding IsFinal resolves this.

Comment: @TroelsLarsen: Yes, that's the test I did :)

Comment: this condition (method.IsVirtual && !method.IsFinal) satisfy for properties too (getter and setter methods like get_PropertyName, set_PropertyName)

Comment: @ElanchezhianNarayanasamy: Are you asking that, or stating it? I'm not sure what the point of your comment it.

Answer (score 1):

Full, working sample:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MethodInfo[] methods = typeof(User).GetMethods();
        foreach (var method in methods)
        {
            if (method.IsVirtual && !method.IsFinal)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(method.Name);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class User : IUser
{
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        // some codes
        return null;
    }
    public virtual string GetData(int id)
    {
        // I want to find this method declared as virtual
        return null;
    }
}

public interface IUser
{
    string Get(int id);
    string GetData(int id);
}
```

Output:

```
GetData
ToString
Equals
GetHashCode
```

Comment: Please mark the other answer if this works for you. I merely pasted it for OP to run.